# Saving TableView column properties and display the changed tableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to make a generic class in javafx that takes any tableView and saves, restores the changes made on its columns order, width.

---

What I have tried so far is I am applying these functionalities on each tableView individually. But I want something like `save(String id, TableView table)` for saving the changes and `restore(String id, TableView table)` to restore the changes made.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code sample to save the current changes made:

```
 saveSetting.setOnAction((event) -> {
               w1 = columns.get(0).getWidth();              
                o1 = columns.get(0).getId();
                w2 = columns.get(1).getWidth();             
                o2 = columns.get(1).getId();
                w3 = columns.get(2).getWidth();
                o3 = columns.get(2).getId();    
            setTable(w1, w2, w3, o1, o2, o3);
       }

       private void setTable(double w1, double w2, double w3, String o1, String o2, String o3) {

        tableView.getColumns().clear();
        TableColumn<Circuit, String> col1 = new TableColumn(o1);
        col1.setId(o1);
        col1.setPrefWidth(w1);


        TableColumn<Circuit, String> col2 = new TableColumn(o2);
        col2.setId(o2);
        col2.setPrefWidth(w2);

        TableColumn<Circuit, String> col3 = new TableColumn(o3);
        col3.setId(o3);
        col3.setPrefWidth(w3);

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(col1, col2, col3);
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: Thanks Manetsus, I hope this will help you understand what have I done so far

Comment: @user5829712: I edited the question, but maybe I didn't understand your intention. If you don't need to save the columns to a **file** (which i thought *save* implies, but with your code I'm not so sure), edit your question title and remove the marshalling tag and add some clarification to in the question.

Comment: @ fabian-- Yess. I need not to save changes to a file. I want to save and display the changes made to the tableView as a whole when I click on save button. Similarly, when I click on restore, TableView should be displayed with the last saved settings of column order and widths.

Comment: I don't see a problem there. You probably should add a few more properties (especially `text`, `cellValueFactory` and `cellFactory`) and use a collection/array of instances of a custom class containing the properties to store the data, but I don't get the problem, since it's not descirbed in the question, why you don't just modify the existing code /, what your specific problem is.

Comment: this is my problem : private void setTable(double w1, double w2, double w3, String o1, String o2, String o3). I need to make it as setTable(tableView)